# How to set TouchImageView width as half of Device`s width and height as Device`s width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to display Two `TouchImageViews` on my `main activity`. I want to set width of each `TouchImageView` to half width of device`s screen size. As well as I want to set height of each`TouchImageView` to width of devices width. I have tried but not getting my desire result. I want result like below image.

[image]

I have tried below code...

`MainActivity.Java`:

```
Display DeviceDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

Point size = new Point();
DeviceDisplay.getSize(size);

int DeviceDisplayWidth = size.x;
int DeviceDisplayHeight = size.y;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(DeviceDisplayWidth / 2, DeviceDisplayHeight);

img_to_be_zoomed.setLayoutParams(params);
img_to_be_zoomed_mirror.setLayoutParams(params);
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_back_description"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_app_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/txt_app_name"
            android:textSize="35px"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_menu"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_menu_description"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_square"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>

        <com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_to_be_zoomed_mirror"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img" >
        </com.PinchZoom.pinchzoomexampletwo.TouchImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_first"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_second"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_third"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_third"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_hscrolling_fourth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_view_fourth"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ddd" >
        </com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need scaleType atribute inside the ImageView

Comment: Use a linear layout with weight, weight sum and orientation?

Comment: Need to set programmatically as device`s size changes.@Skynet
I have tried scale type to fitXY, centerCrop but not getting@yshahak

Answer (score 0):

try this code.. set your image view width and height as run time.

```
 private void setImageView() {
    // adding a view tree observer on image container

YourLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            // remove predrawlistener
            YourLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            setImageViewParams();
            return true;
        }
    });

    YourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver
            .OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            // remove predrawlistener
            YourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            setImageViewParams();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void setImageViewParams() {
    if (YourImageView.getHeight() == 0 || rootView.getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.getLayoutParams();
    int imageViewPostion = (rootView.getWidth()/2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = (Linear.LayoutParams) yourImageview.getLayoutParams();
    imageViewLayoutParams.setWidth = positonAfterImageContainer;
    iamgeViewLayoutParams.setHeight = positonAfterImageContainer;
    imageViewID.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
}
```